# jQuery: .data("id") on new element doesn't work

Tags: jquery

It is a very trivial code, but I don't know where the problem lies.
So I have this code on my Client:

```
socket.on('newRoom', function (data){
    var newTr = $("<tr>");
    newTr.attr("data-id", data.roomId);
    $('table').append(newTr);
});
```

And this is the code that i want to execute:

```
$('table tr').on('click', function() {
    console.log($(this).data("id")); /* This code doesnt't work */
    console.log("test"); /* This code works */
});
```

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: When you say doesn't work...is the console just showing `undefined`?

Comment: Why are you using data attributes in the first place? If you have a data structure of sequential elements, why use the DOM to store information about them? Store information about them in JavaScript objects and data bind them to the DOM. If you trust your DOM as the source of truth in your application you're likely going to have design problems eventually.

Comment: Seems working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Am8NU/)

Comment: Why do you use .attr instead of .data? How is your event even being triggered since it's a dynamic element and you're not rebinding the event or using event delegation?

Comment: Are you using a very old version of jQuery?

Comment: @tymeJV No, it just doesn't shows up.

Comment: @KevinB I need to store data.roomID outside of the .on function.

Comment: @TheFilipo That doesn't answer .attr vs .data though. If you stored it with .data("key",value) it would work the same way you are doing .attr

Comment: @TheFilipo does `data.roomId` actually contain a proper value?

Comment: @robertklep Thx, to your post. I actually solved it, my problem was that the eventhandler was added before the tr was added. Post it again and I will accept the answer.

Comment: @TheFilipo good to hear it solved your problem, although I don't quite understand why; @tymeVJ made a valid point about the `test` message being shown, so the click handler did get called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably installing the event handler *before* the `tr` is added to the DOM. In your example, you're using direct events, which only work if the targetted element(s) (`table tr`) already exist in the DOM.

To handle events for elements that aren't (yet) in the DOM, you need to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  console.log($(this).data("id"));
  console.log("test");
});
```

That way, the event handler is attached to an element that is already in the DOM (the `table` element, although I'm assuming that's not generated as well), and `click` events will be delegated to the (dynamically inserted) `tr` element(s).

Comment: I don't think this is it..the `console.log("test")` is still firing in the OP's original code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
console.log($(this).attr("data-id"));
```

instead of your code.